# get value 'name' form second array

Tags: php, html

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(9292)
    ["name"]=>
    string(41) "Voetbal : Limburg - 1ste Ploegen - Hommes"
    ["ranking"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(9442)
    ["name"]=>
    string(48) "Voetbal : Antwerpen - Eerste Elftallen. - Hommes"
    ["ranking"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(48358)
    ["name"]=>
    string(41) "Voetbal : Antwerpen - Beker Heren groep 6"
    ["ranking"]=>
    array(33) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#4 (40) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(184343)
        ["name"]=>
        string(46) "Voetbal : K.S.V. OUD-TURNHOUT Eerste Elftallen"
      }
      [32]=>
      object(stdClass)#68 (40) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(186558)
        ["name"]=>
        string(40) "Voetbal : K.F.C. POPPEL Eerste Elftallen"
      }
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#70 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(48366)
    ["name"]=>
    string(31) "Voetbal : Antwerpen - 3 PROV. C"
    ["ranking"]=>
    array(16) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#71 (40) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(186550)
        ["name"]=>
        string(46) "Voetbal : F.C. ARENDONK SPORT Eerste Elftallen"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#73 (40) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(186544)
        ["name"]=>
        string(44) "Voetbal : K. ZWALUWEN OLMEN Eerste Elftallen"
      }
      [15]=>
      object(stdClass)#101 (40) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(184389)
        ["name"]=>
        string(38) "Voetbal : F.C. GIERLE Eerste Elftallen"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
foreach ($data as $val){
echo $val->id . ' - '.  $val->name . '<br>';
}
?>
```

then i get this as result :  9292 - Voetbal : Limburg - 1ste Ploegen - Hommes
9442 - Voetbal : Antwerpen - Eerste Elftallen. - Hommes
48358 - Voetbal : Antwerpen - Beker Heren groep 6
48366 - Voetbal : Antwerpen - 3 PROV. C

But i need the name from the second array in the first array

i need to get the name '["name"]=> string(46) "Voetbal : F.C. ARENDONK SPORT Eerste Elftallen"'
from the array

Comment: What “second” array? You have shown _one_ array. Are you talking about the sub-array under the key `ranking`? Not all of your arrays on the first level _have_ data in there, and some of those that do, have _multiple_ items. Give us a proper explanation of what you need in each of those cases.

Comment: First array from 0 ->3 , i need from 3 " [3]=> object(stdClass)#70 (3) ["name"]=>
    string(31) "Voetbal : Antwerpen - 3 PROV. C", i need to create a ranking of the teams in this sub array. 0]=> object(stdClass)#71 (40) {name]=>"Voetbal : F.C. ARENDONK SPORT Eerste Elftallen"; [1]=> object(stdClass)#73 (40) { ["id"]=>        int(186544) ["name"]=>  string(44) "Voetbal : K. ZWALUWEN OLMEN Eerste lftallen" and so futher

Comment: This is hardly readable in comments. Plus, I rather wanted you to explain the _logic_ by which you want to get what from where, and not just give the expected result for this specific set of data (which is likely not fixed, I suppose, but might contain more entries in the future?)

Answer (score 0):

If you need only Voetbal : F.C. ARENDONK SPORT Eerste Elftallen,
something like this should work:

```
$data[3]->ranking[0]
```

I haven't tested this, but I think this should work